# Sorting a list in progressive numeric order

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Example file list:

- 1.jpg
- 2.jpg
- 3.jpg
- 22.jpg

easy cycle for iterating the list

```
for /r %j in (*.jpg) do @echo %~nxj
```

The gives the following result:

```
1
2
22
3
```

How can i order the results consecutively, like below?

```
1
2
3
22
```

thanks everyone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read files in directory in order of filename prefix with batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748744/read-files-in-directory-in-order-of-filename-prefix-with-batch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just made this for you it seems that your way would of worked but there is a simpler way of doing it.

```
@echo off
del /q /s /f "%temp%\TEMP.tmp">nul
dir /b *.* >> %temp%\TEMP.tmp
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type %temp%\TEMP.tmp') do ( 
    set "Var=%%x"
    ECHO !Var!
)
pause
```

Put the bat file in the same dir as the pictures.

Comment: This code will not work as requested (increasing value) on an NTFS drive if the sort-order is altered to strict-alphabetical (the Win-2000 scheme - see https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/319827/the-sort-order-for-files-and-folders-whose-names-contain-numerals-is-d ). Nor will it work for FAT-style devices (like most ramdrives, SD cards, etc.) unless the files are created in strict-numerical sequence, so if the files on an SD device are created sequentially as 22.jpg, 3.jpg, 2.jpg, 1.jpg then this routine will report them in *that* order, not in the sequence specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
(
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg" ') DO (
  SET /a seq=1000000000+%%~na
  ECHO !seq!) 
)>"%temp%\tempfile"

FOR /f %%a IN ('sort "%temp%\tempfile"') DO (
 SET /a seq=%%a-1000000000
  ECHO !seq!.jpg) 
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you - of course, you'd need to set your own `sourcedir`, the temp filename is up to you, it's not cleaned up and it will only work with pure-numeric filenames without leading zeroes <1000000000. The `.jpg` extension is assumed.