# Enumeration when merging files by a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, merge

I have a batch that's merging some files into one file called `all.txt`. The batch code is OK, but what I want is to concatenate the file contents in numerical order. Currently the command will start merging files in this order.

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
100,001.txt
3000.txt
```

What I want is merge `001.txt` to `100,001.txt` in numerical order:

```
 1.txt
 2.txt
 3.txt
 3000.txt
 100,001.txt
```

This is my current code:

```
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do (
    type "%%~a"
    echo(
  )
)>all.txt
```

Comment: _me_ thinks that 001 - 300 000 is not alphabetical, rather numerical order.

Comment: For your `dir` options choose to sort by name `('DIR/A-D-S-L/B/ON *.txt')`. Type and enter `DIR/?` into a Command prompt window for an explanation of the options available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a 2014 answer by Magoo, Link pasted in a comment on his answer below.
This takes the files and adds an number to them and writes it to a tempfile, the temp file is then sorted numerically and the amount is deducted and read in that order.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') DO (
  set /a "seq=1000000000+%%~na"
  echo !seq!) 
)>"%temp%\tempfile"

for /f %%a IN ('sort "%temp%\tempfile"') DO (
 set /a "seq=%%a-1000000000"
 type !seq!.txt
 echo(
)>> all.log
```

This will write the files in sequence:

`001.txt
002.txt
3000.txt
100001.txt`

**Please note the following!**
I named the output file `all.log`. The reason being that you are reading all text files and if you name it `all.txt` it will be read as well.

Also, if any other files exists in the directory which are not numerically named, it will attempt to do the same calculation. This calculation will only work on files that are numerically named.

Comment: This is exactly what i want , thank you very much Gerhard !!! But please i want just to modify something : the files that i've are nammed like this : Gerhard.1.txt , Gerhard.2.txt ..... so with this code it can't works with files that begins with a name then a number .... because this code works only with numbers files ... is there any modification in the script BATCH ? (i don't want to rename files with date of creation ...) . thank's .

Comment: will all names be the same? only numbers change? so all files will be `filename001` `filename002` etc? or will the file alphabetical names change as well?

Comment: anyway, if the file names are going to be the same, only numbers changing, then you will strip away the name and leave only the numbers, do the same as above and then add the name again after the sort. If however it is not a static name with numeric changes, then it will be a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want alphabetically?

```
'dir /b /a-d /on *.txt'
```

should do that - but it's the default on NTFS so unless you're sourcing your files from a FAT drive where they'd be in random order, you should have the files alphabetically without the modification.

What do **YOU** mean by `alphabetically`?

Comment: think he means numerical order :)

Comment: ok, so when I re-read it, he says that he is getting file 100001 before 3000 which should be other way around. so this answer you posted back in 2014 was for a similar question. I will give you the honors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544268/sorting-a-list-in-progressive-numeric-order

Comment: I edited his question to clarify, waiting on peer review.

Comment: @GUESTOSS So did you perhaps look at my answer yet? I took the link and modified the content of that script by Magoo which is working.

Comment: The Verified answer : This is exactly what i want , thank you very much Gerhard !!! But please i want just to modify something : the files that i've are nammed like this : Gerhard.1.txt , Gerhard.2.txt ..... so with this code it can't works with files that begins with a name then a number .... because this code works only with numbers files ... is there any modification in the script BATCH ? (i don't want to rename files with date of creation ...) . thank's .