# Concatenate all files from a directory in natural order

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have some files in `C:\TEST` directory with custom naming convention as following

- 102_File1.txt
- 1_File1.txt
- 10_File1.txt
- 2_File1.txt
- 3_File1.txt
- 202_File1.txt

I want to concatenate the content of every `*.txt` file of `C:\Test` directory into single file.

I have code snippet of batch file like this : `FOR /r "C:\Test" %%F IN (*.txt) DO ( process content of the file)`

BUT using above code snippet, it concatenates all the files in normal sorting order as follows

- 102_File1.txt
- 10_File1.txt
- 1_File1.txt
- 203_File1.txt
- 2_File1.txt
- 3_File1.txt

I want to concatenate all files in a natural numbering order so that newly created file with have concatenated content in following sequence only

- 1_File1.txt
- 2_File1.txt
- 3_File1.txt
- 10_File1.txt
- 102_File1.txt
- 202_File1.txt

How can I achieve this using batch script?

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748744/read-files-in-directory-in-order-of-filename-prefix-with-batch) gives you something!

Comment: Hi, DanielLuz , that solution didn't work for me.. :(